# Javascript method usage

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

While going through the examples of KnockoutJS, I saw the below [code](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail).

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { self.chosenFolderId(folder); };    
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

I am not an expert in Javascript, but bit confused by the usage `self.chosenFolderId(folder);`

chosenFolderId is a property, and assigned `ko.observable();` From the experience with other languages,

1. How can one invoke it by passing an argument like `self.chosenFolderId(folder);`
2. Where is folder defines?

If you can just point to an article which explains this that will do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chosenFolderId` is a property, but properties may be functions (and must be, in this case).

So `ko.observable` returns a function that takes a single argument (the folder).

It's no different than the next line:

```
self.goToFolder = function(folder) { ... };
```

where the `goToFolder` property is being set to a function.

`folder` itself is "defined" as a parameter as `goToFolder`'s parameter. Whatever *calls* `goToFolder` provides a value for `folder`.

Comment: thanks Dave. So parameter (folder) doesn't have to be a specific type. I kind of know JS is dynamic in nature. So, the type information doesn't need?

Comment: @bsreekanth It's almost certain it needs to be a certain type, or contain a value meaningful to the framework--*what* that type or value looks like, I don't know. You could determine what it is by putting a breakpoint in the `goToFolder` function or just logging it.

Comment: For a ref. It succinctly explains here .. http://javascript.about.com/library/blargs.htm The most obvious differences are that Javascript does not use strong data typing and so arguments don't have a type specified for them but instead take on whatever data type is passed to them. Also Javascript is interpreted and not compiled so any mismatches would be detected at run time rather than compile time since there is no compile step.

Comment: @bsreekanth There's a compile step in most (all?) modern JavaScripts, it's just that it's typically invisible to the user, for example, in a browser context. And my point was that the parameter *does* need to be a specific type and/or value, just that there's no way to specify what that type and/or value is outside of code in current JS.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in javascript are first-class objects. `ko.observable()` is a function call, and its return value is itself a function.

Basically I can do something like this:

```
var observable = function(some_param) {
  return function(some_other_param) {
    // do something useful here
  }
}
```

Then I can call:

```
observable(1)(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript functions can be assigned to variables, passed to functions as arguments, returned from functions and so on. In other words, the'yre [First-class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).